# Snapping a UIView to a set position after panGesture release

Tags: objective-c, uiview, center, uipangesturerecognizer, xcode4.4

I am playing with **XCode** at the moment, but **have no experience with Objective-C / Cocoa Touch etc** so bear with me if this is a terribly rudimentary question. I only ask you guys because I've been trying to Google an answer for days, and am getting bored of dead ends.

**I am trying to create a horizontally panning menu.**

I am currently holding 3 `UILabels` inside a master `UIView` object, which is attached to a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

I have used a handlePan method to receive and translate the ***menuview** `UIView` object according to the user's pan gesture, but I need to find the `UIView`'s center coordinates when the **PanGesture** is released to calculate where to snap the `UIView` element back/forward to.

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, 150);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    if(recognizer.view.center.x >= 576);{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        menuview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation((764 - menuview.center.x), 0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }

    if(recognizer.view.center.x && menuview.center.x >= 264);{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        menuview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation((406 - menuview.center.x), 0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }

    if(recognizer.view.center.x < 264);{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        menuview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation((122 - menuview.center.x), 0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }

}
```

}

You see I was trying to snap to one of three points on the x-axis, depending on where the center of the `UIView` is when the user releases their `PanGesture`.

At the moment, it is acting as if it's ignoring the "**recognizer.view.center.x**" if statements, as no matter where it is released it snaps to **x=122 (122 - menuview.center.x)**.

I have tried these if statements with:

```
if(menuview.center.x >= 576);{...
```

etc, but that also fails.

What do I need to be putting in these if statements to create actions based ont he `UIViews` CURRENT position when the user releases their `PanGesture`?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use, hopefully it will help you:

.h

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

delcare these two floats

```
float firstX;
float firstY;
```

.m

```
-(void)moveHorizontallyAndVertically:(id)sender {
[[[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view] layer] removeAllAnimations];

//  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];
CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];
if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    firstX = [myView center].x;
    firstY = [myView center].y;


}

translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

[myView setCenter:translatedPoint];

if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    CGFloat finalX = translatedPoint.x + (0.0*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].x);
    CGFloat finalY = translatedPoint.y + (0.0*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].y);
    if(finalX < 0) {
        finalX = 0;
    }
    else if(finalX > 320) {
        finalX = 320;
    }
    if(finalY < 0) {
        finalY = 0;
    }
    else if(finalY > 480) {
        finalY = 480;
    }
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [myView setCenter:CGPointMake(finalX, finalY)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

}

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for replying!

This code doesn't seem to work for me, I'm afraid. It was saying that I was using an unidentified 'sender', so I switched it out for 'recognizer' I'd used in the handlePan method. This got rid of the red error, but didn't work.

And it also didn't like "translatedPoint.x", gave me a red fail error, and asked if I wanted to change it to "translation.x". But even after changing that, it didn't seem to be working.

The UIView slide around fine, but dones't snap back to any position now...

Comment: Ah, you hero! I am so new to this that all tying all the elements together in .h's and .m's all over the shop is taking a while to sink in. Thank you SO much for your help.

Comment: How and where do you use this? Shouldn't be handling a (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer

Answer (score 0):

I did this also by simply setting a new frame with CGRectMake in the animation block. Also done in UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{ 
                               NSLog(@"before: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(piece.center));
                               piece.frame = CGRectMake(targImgView.frame.origin.x,
                               targImgView.frame.origin.y,                                                                                      
                               targImgView.frame.size.width,
                               targImgView.frame.size.height);                                                                      
                               NSLog(@"after: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(piece.center));
                              } 
                  completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all possible using Interface Builder and Autolayout. Here is the code I used to do this:

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *buttonXConstraint;  
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *buttonYConstraint;
```

Then hook up those `IBOutlets` to the Horizontal Constraint(X Position) and Vertical Constraint(Y Position) in the Interface Builder. Make sure that the Constraints are hooked up to the base view and not it's closest view.

Hook up a pan gesture and then use this following code to drag your object around:

```
- (IBAction)panPlayButton:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
  if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){

  } else if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){
     CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];

     //Update the constraint's constant
     self.buttonXConstraint.constant += translation.x;
     self.buttonYConstraint.constant += translation.y;

     // Assign the frame's position only for checking it's fully on the screen
     CGRect recognizerFrame = sender.view.frame;
     recognizerFrame.origin.x = self.buttonXConstraint.constant;
     recognizerFrame.origin.y = self.buttonYConstraint.constant;

     // Check if UIImageView is completely inside its superView
     if(!CGRectContainsRect(self.view.bounds, recognizerFrame)) {
         if (self.buttonYConstraint.constant < CGRectGetMinY(self.view.bounds)) {
             self.buttonYConstraint.constant = 0;
         } else if (self.buttonYConstraint.constant + CGRectGetHeight(recognizerFrame) > CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds)) {
             self.buttonYConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(recognizerFrame);
         }

         if (self.buttonXConstraint.constant < CGRectGetMinX(self.view.bounds)) {
             self.buttonXConstraint.constant = 0;
         } else if (self.buttonXConstraint.constant + CGRectGetWidth(recognizerFrame) > CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds)) {
             self.buttonXConstraint.constant = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(recognizerFrame);
         }
     }

     //Layout the View
     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
 } else if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
```